# How to undock and separate a form that is docked in another form in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

What i want to do:

- Have two separate forms
- Drag the first form in the second form and dock it in a panel of that second form.
- After that i want to be able to drag the first form back out of the second form and make it stand on it's own again.

Dragging and docking the first form in the second form works. But i can't get the form back out of the second form. When i drag it out, it disappears.

Because the dragging and dropping makes the example code more complicated than necessary i left it out. Instead i used buttons. The example form has two buttons and a panel. When button one is pressed the form puts a copy of itself in the panel. When button two is pressed the copy form should be undocked and showing as a separate form. This last part doesn't work. Instead the copy form disappears.

Is what i am trying to do not possible, or am i doing something wrong?

**EDIT: from Hans' comment now i know what's wrong. I changed the code below to make it work. I put a comment behind the code line that is changed**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form1 CopyForm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CopyForm == null)
        {
            CopyForm = new Form1();
            CopyForm.TopLevel = false;
            CopyForm.Parent = panel1;
            CopyForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            CopyForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            CopyForm.Show();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CopyForm.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        CopyForm.Parent = null;

        panel1.Controls.Clear();

        CopyForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
        CopyForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        CopyForm.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        CopyForm.TopMost = true;
        CopyForm.TopLevel = true; // <== This line was the fix to my problem
        CopyForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its TopLevel property is still false, so disappears from view without a Parent.

Comment: Yeah that is the solution! Thanks man! I swapped Topmost and Toplevel by accedent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out,
CopyForm.TopLevel was not set to true in the button2_Click method.
Adding `CopyForm.TopLevel = true;` made the form show up!
Thanks Hans!